# Should the smooth side or the rough side of a urethane bandsaw tire go against the wheel?

Tags: tools, powertools, bandsaw

I am replacing bandsaw tires. I bought urethane replacement tires. There is a smooth side and a rough side. The manufacturers directions are clear on every step except for this point. The old tires have been on the bandsaw for AT LEAST 25 years and are made of rubber, those two differences make me leery of simply mirroring the current setup.

Does the smooth side or the rough side of the tire go against the bandsaw wheel?

If it matters the wheel is made of aluminum, the wheel itself has a crown, and the wheel has a lip on the edge to hold the tire on.

Comment: Did the old "tires"  provide any clues for you ? Are there instructions with your new tires or info in the band saw's  service manual concerning the installation of  "tires"  ?  Have you tried looking up your models manufacturers website or contacting them ? Perhaps the woodworking stack would be a better place since a band saw is more common in woodworking than in DIY home improvement.

Comment: @AlaskaMan - Thanks for the lead on Woodworking.SE. I made edits to address your other points.

Comment: Crossposted to Woodworking.SE - https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/10488/should-the-smooth-side-or-the-rough-side-of-a-urethane-bandsaw-tire-go-against-t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote to the manufacturer, they replied:

> Either way will work.  However I install smooth side in to the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

I actually have the same question. I recently bought
Blue Max bandsaw tires and out of the package
the rough side was out. Also on a YouTube video
where Blue Max tires were being installed it looked
like the smooth side was against the wheel.
It is my guess that with Blue Max at least the rough
side is out.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

When I've seen these installed, the outside that the blade tracks on seems very smooth.  I would guess you want it smooth for the lowest "rolling resistance", so I would install it with the rougher side against the wheel.

That said, I've never installed one myself, and I can't seem to find anyone mentioning a smooth side and a rough side.